# Visualforce bar chart

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-charting

How do I show the count of the records based on the created date-month(monthly) on a bar chart using Visualforce charting. Any example of getting record count through SOQL is much appreciated. (Record count on X-axis, months on Y-axis). I went through the documentation but unable to figure out how to display it monthly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to get the record count per year and month using SOQL with [aggregate](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm) and [date](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) functions:

```
public with sharing class ChartController {

    public class Month {
        public Integer year {get; set;}
        public Integer month {get; set;}
        public Integer count {get; set;}
        public String yearMonth {get; set; }
        Month(Integer year, Integer month, Integer count) {
            this.year = year;
            this.month = month;
            this.count = count;
            this.yearMonth = year + '/' + month;
        }
    }

    public Month[] getMonths() {
        Month[] months = new Month[] {};
        for (AggregateResult ar : [
                select
                        CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) y,
                        CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) m,
                        COUNT(Id) c
                from Contact
                group by CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate), CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate)
                order by CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate), CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate)
                ]) {
            months.add(new Month(
                    (Integer) ar.get('y'),
                    (Integer) ar.get('m'),
                    (Integer) ar.get('c')
                    ));
        }
        return months;
    }
}
```

and the corresponding chart page:

```
<apex:page controller="ChartController">
    <apex:chart height="400" width="400" data="{!months}">
        <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="count"
                title="Record Count"/>
        <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="yearMonth"
                title="Year/Month"/>
        <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left"
                xField="yearMonth" yField="count"/>
    </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

and an example of the output produced:

[image: screen shot of chart]

Some Apex code should be added to fill in the months that have no data.

Comment: Thanks Keith, is there anyway that I could stack the chart based on picklist values and display the month name instead of number?

Comment: @cartman You can change the line `this.yearMonth = year + '/' + month;` to reference a map that translates the month number to a month name. And yes, you can add multiple fields instead of `count` and produce a [stacked chart](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_charting_appearance_bar_charts.htm).